# Prevent screensaver starting when an application runs fullscreen

Tags: windows-vista, screensaver, desktop-environments

Is there a way to prevent the screensaver from running when a certain application is running, in Windows Vista?

I'm asking because I know Windows MediaPlayer does this, but the kind people at [Pinnacle Systems](http://www.pinnaclesys.com/) seem to have forgotten this, at least in the TVCenter application that came with my pctv100e

Comment: I would think it would be a easy task to create a small program you could run that would fix this. What I mean is, you could alter your shortcut to run a small program instead of the actual program, passing the actual program command line to that small program. The small program would turn off screen saver and other things (liker power saving options), start and wait for the actual program, then turn back on the things it disabled.

Comment: Please add this as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 4):

As workaround: there is a little utility named **flipss.exe** which can be used to easily enable or disable the screensaver via a command line argument.

See this links for details: [**Create Shortcut Icon to Disable / Enable the Screensaver**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-shortcut-icon-to-disable-enable-the-screensaver/)

You can use this utility in a batch file as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use these to stop your screensaver from activating:

[Caffine for Mac](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/)

[Caffine for Windows](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/index.html)

I find them useful when watching programmes on BBC iPlayer, or long tech talks on YouTube.

Answer (score 3):

Try [ScreenSaver Commander](http://www.bdvnotepad.com/products/screensaver-commander/).
 It is screen saver manager and it allows you to set a list of conditions to prevent screen saver from running.

You can create a list of conditions in program to *prevent starting of screen saver when specified applications are running*.