# How to suppress screen saver when a given program is running?

Tags: windows, screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent screensaver starting when an application runs fullscreen.](https://superuser.com/questions/9081/prevent-screensaver-starting-when-an-application-runs-fullscreen)

E.g when I am viewing a movie & making no ipnut. At other times I want my screensaver to kick in after 3 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at something like **[Caffeine](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2009/05/caffeine-disables-or-enables-the-screensaver-easily/)**...

> Tiny utility Caffeine disables or enables the screensaver by simply double-clicking on the icon in the system tray—so you can watch that YouTube video without your screensaver kicking in.

Comment: +1. Thanks. That seems ok, although I woudl rather automate it. II will keep looking